# WPF application DispatchTimer updates every two seconds instead of one

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to call a method every second using DispatcherTimer(); this works fine when updating the timer, however whenever I try to update any UI Emements in the method the timer seems to tick every 2 seconds instead of every second and the more UI elements I add to update increases the tick time, also the window cant be dragged around the screen between the ticks.

How can I get the time to update every second correctly?

I'm querying a web api to receive data. I wonder could this be the problem?

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    var dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(DispatcherTimer_Tick);
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}        

private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    // Updating the Label which displays the current second
    lblTime.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

    lblSizeBTC_USD.Content = "SIZE " + Api.GetProductTicker(productId).Result.size;            

    // Forcing the CommandManager to raise the RequerySuggested event
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}
```

Method calling the web api

```
public static async Task<ProductTicker> GetProductTicker(string productId)
{
    string ts = GetNonce();
    string method = "/products/" + productId + "/ticker";
    string sig = GetSignature(ts, "GET", method, string.Empty);
    ProductTicker productTicker;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseURL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CB-ACCESS-KEY", apiKey);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CB-ACCESS-SIGN", sig);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP", ts);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE", passphrase);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", userAgent);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(method).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        productTicker = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductTicker>(json);
    }

    return productTicker;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use Task.Result. Call `await client.GetAsync(method)` and `await pi.GetProductTicker(productId)` instead. Declare the Tick handler `async`.

Comment: Thanks Clemens for taking the time to help, you pointed me to the soloution. I will update and post the working code.

Comment: See my edit to you answer for how you should generally do this. GetProductTicker is already async. No need for Task.Run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clemens was indeed correct the working updated code is below. The solution was to make the `DispatcherTimer_Tick` method async and to await the `GetProductTicker` call:

```
private async void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    // Updating the Label which displays the current second
    lblTime.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

    var productTicker = await Api.GetProductTicker(productId);

    lblSizeBTC_USD.Content = "SIZE " + productTicker.size;        

    // Forcing the CommandManager to raise the RequerySuggested event
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}
```